# Python TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not OrderedDict

Tags: python, base64, decode, ordereddictionary

I have used a Salesforce python package to query the API via SOAP, and it has returned me a base64 serialized ordered dict. How would I go about decoding this to an ordered dictionary?

Comment: base64 is a binary-to-text encoding scheme. How was your binary serialized? `pickle`? You are reporting an error in your title, please provide the calling code in a [mcve]. Check out [ask] while you are at it...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [`b64decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html), followed by [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: Yes. But first things first, you should show us what the b64decode result looks like. Maybe it yields well formed JSON, maybe it's something else.